# TypeError: React.PropTypes is undefined in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I tried to insert tabs for UI built using React.js. I downloaded react-tabs using following command:

```
npm install react-tabs-navigation
```

It caused following error when I imported react-tabs-navigation.

```
import Tabs from 'react-tabs-navigation'
```

Error:

```
TypeError: React.PropTypes is undefined
./node_modules/react-simpletabs/dist/react-simpletabs.js/
node_modules/react-simpletabs/dist/react-simpletabs.js:78
var Tabs = React.createClass({
displayName: 'Tabs',
propTypes: {
className: React.PropTypes.oneOfType([
React.PropTypes.array,
React.PropTypes.string,
React.PropTypes.object
```

How can I overcome this?

Comment: Try prefered methd , import React, { PropTypes  } from 'react'; and 

ComponentName.propTypes = {
}

Comment: PropTypes has been removed from `React v15.5`, and has been moved to separate package `prop-types`

Answer (score -1):

You can downgrade react, or better yet, fork the react-simpletabs library, fix it to use [prop-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types) and submit a pull request. Use the fork until your PR is merged.

Answer (score -1):

what you can do is install dependency of Prop-types from here.

https://github.com/facebook/prop-types#installation

After installation import in your project like this:

> import PropTypes from 'prop-types'; // ES6
>
> var PropTypes = require('prop-types'); // ES5 with npm

And in your project do changes like this:

```
    var Tabs = React.createClass({
displayName: 'Tabs',
propTypes: {
className: PropTypes.oneOfType([
PropTypes.array,
PropTypes.string,
PropTypes.object
```

After that let me know does it work for you or not. :)

Comment: well, if ProTypes are deprecated, so is createClass from react. Also the problem seems to be not from the OP own project but a dependency library

Comment: I tried it @getumangon, but not working still gives error. And following part is in react-simpletabs.js file:
 var Tabs = React.createClass({
displayName: 'Tabs',
propTypes: {
className: PropTypes.oneOfType([
PropTypes.array,
PropTypes.string,
PropTypes.object